# Foreach elements - just the first element works

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using laravel with blade and i'm getting data from database to insert in view with a foreach. Each element have an id that display a popup but just work for the first element and i don't understand why.
Even though the first click be in the third element is for example either. only works on the first element.

The data show correctly, the problem is just with jquery click.

My jquery:

```
function getEditFolder(){
 $( "#edit-folder" ).click(function(e)
 {
   alert("edit folder");
   var linkPopup = $(this).attr('data-popup');
   $.get(linkPopup, function(response)
   {
      $( ".opacity" ).css("display","block");
      $( ".popup" ).css("display","block");
      $('.popup').html(response);
      componentHandler.upgradeDom();
      $(".popup-close i").click(function()
      {
         $( ".popup .mdl-card" ).remove();
         $( ".popup" ).css("display","none");
         $( ".opacity" ).css("display","none");
      });
   });
   e.preventDefault();
 });}
```

my view:

```
<div id="slide">
@foreach ($groups as $group)
  <div class="folder" data-history="{{$group->historico}}" data-dir="{{$group->directoria}}">
    <div class="folder-icon-name">
      <div class="folder-icon">
        <i class="material-icons md-24">folder</i>
      </div>
      <div class="folder-op">
        <div class="update-icon">
          <i id="edit-folder" class="material-icons" data-popup="app/edit-folder">mode_edit</i>
        </div>
        <div class="download-icon">
          <i class="material-icons">cloud_download</i>
        </div>
        <div class="remove-icon">
          <i id="remove-folder" class="material-icons" data-popup="app/remove-folder">delete</i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="folder-name">
        <span>{{$group->grupo}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
@endforeach</div>
```

SOLUTION:
The id is unique so i have to use class.

Thank's

Comment: Element `id`s must be unique. Use a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, you need to use a class instead of an ID.
An ID can only be assigned to a single element, so jQuery is matching the first element it finds and then stopping.

If you use a class then it will allow you to use the same action on each instance of the button.

```
<i class="material-icons edit-folder" data-popup="app/edit-folder">mode_edit</i>
```

and the JS:

```
function getEditFolder(){
 $( ".edit-folder" ).click(function(e)
 {
   alert("edit folder");
   var linkPopup = $(this).attr('data-popup');
   $.get(linkPopup, function(response)
   {
      $( ".opacity" ).css("display","block");
      $( ".popup" ).css("display","block");
      $('.popup').html(response);
      componentHandler.upgradeDom();
      $(".popup-close i").click(function()
      {
         $( ".popup .mdl-card" ).remove();
         $( ".popup" ).css("display","none");
         $( ".opacity" ).css("display","none");
      });
   });
   e.preventDefault();
 });}
```